# Why does it work in this class does not work in another class

Tags: c#, mvvm, httpclient

I have 2 viewmodel, aviewmodel and bviewmodel. in aviewmodel and bviewmodel are used method GetListEmployees(). i have a problem. 
In aviewmodel,I have successfully run the GetListEmployees().but in bviewmodel then it does not work. I debug and I see it was thrown when it came to response. I don't know why it's like that.

video description. https://youtu.be/CD3lHKx3igs

Function to get the list.

```
async private Task GetListEmployees()
    {
        var result = await GeneralMethods.Ins.GetDataFromDB<Employee>("Employee/employees");
       // ListEmployee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(result);
    }
```

This is class read api.

```
 public class GeneralMethods
{
    private static GeneralMethods _Ins;

    public static GeneralMethods Ins
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Ins == null)
                _Ins = new GeneralMethods();
            return GeneralMethods._Ins;
        }
        private set
        {
            GeneralMethods._Ins = value;
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> GetDataFromDB<T>(string urlDB)
    {
        string url = "http://webapi.local/api/" + urlDB;

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await APIHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<T>>().Result;

                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

APIHelper

```
 public static class APIHelper
{
    public static HttpClient ApiClient { get; set; }

    public static void InitializeClient()
    {
        ApiClient = new HttpClient();
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are telling us it throws an exception, then its worth while pasting it. They tell you whats wrong, and more importantly, they tell us whats wrong

Comment: HttpResponseMessage response = await APIHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(url).It didn't work if or else. It skipped running through using.

Comment: Have you compared the values of  `url = "http://webapi.local/api/" + urlDB` upon debugging?

Comment: i did. i sure url is correct